# Cythonise a pandas loop

Tags: python, pandas, cython

Can anyone help show me how convert this loop into cython to improve performance. I get you need to create static types using cdef for performance but what else is required:

If I have a dataframe df with column 'a'.

```
 for i in range(0, len(df.a)-1):
     if (i < len(df.a)-1):
         y= i + 1
         while ((np.abs(df.a[y]- df.a[i]) <= 0.015) & (y < len(df.a)-1)):
             y = y + 1
         if df[a][y] - df[a][i] >= 0.015:
             df['dir_y'][i] = 1
             #print(1)
         else:
             df['dir_y'][i] = -1
             #print(-1)
```

I am pretty sure 'cythonise' is not a word it just seemed appropriate.

Comment: perhaps you can first look at `.iloc` and `.ix`, optimise your existing code, profile again then decide if you need to move to *cython*?

Comment: See also the pandas docs on extending with cython:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#cython-writing-c-extensions-for-pandas

Comment: Anzel can you elabortae on why .iloc and .ix would be faster. I thought .ix is slower than what i have written

Comment: Your code is convoluted and in desperate need of vectorization.  I wouldn't recommend that you use cython until you've cleaned this up.  I may have time to look at later today.

Comment: Thanks, I assume you are thinking vectorise the for loop correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without trying to comment on whether you could write this better in Pandas without using Cython (I don't know, but it's certainly worth trying), the steps you'd need to do are:

1. `cdef` the iteration indices `i` and `y` as integers: `cdef int i,y` (the cdefs go at the top of the function they're in)
2. `cdef` a memoryview array to access `df.a`/`df['a']` through: `cdef double[:] df_a_mv` then later `df_a_mv = df.a` (I've guessed at the type here, but it's probably double)
3. Replace all your `df.a` with your memoryview (`df_a_mv`)
4. Compile in Cython (see http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html)

You probably also want to run `cython -a <your_file>.pyx` to see what it has done - it generates an HTML file and lines highlighted in yellow are the unoptimised bits.

I wouldn't worry about `df['dir_y'][i]` - it gets done fairly infrequently and you probably can't speed them up too much.

As a final small point: `if (i < len(df.a)-1):` is unnecessary - it's guaranteed by the surrounding `for` loop.